# Desktop Program That Notifies When Web Cam Is Being Accessed

Tags: java, windows, macos, desktop-application

I'm trying to find a developer to write a *desktop* program that has a pretty basic function. It will notify users, via some dialog (or alert) that some program is about to access the *web cam*. It could be skype or facetime, or whatever it is, the program should be aware of when the OS's camera is going to be accessed and notify the user. Yes, even if the user is initiating the camera themselves via Skype, the notification would still appear.

My question is this. If I need this program written in Java, is it possible? Obviously I am trying to get it done in Java so it would run on Windows *and* Mac.

If it is not possible, then it seems as though I'd have to write 2 separate programs on Windows and Mac.

I've come here to get suggestions so that I can connect with the right developers. If you have any suggestions, I'd be happy to hear them. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't write this in Java. Whatever approach you take will be very system-specific (and will probably require enhanced privileges). You could write a JNI library and a Java interface, but it'd probably be about the same amount of trouble to write programs to the native UI libraries.

Comment: thanks for the comment. I have updated the answer to specify that it's access to the web cam. Don't know if it changes your answer or not.

Comment: No, there's no difference. Interfering with other programs' access to system resources will require interacting with system-level APIs. The sort of camera in use is irrelevant, and in the case of Linux at least, gets abstracted by the OS API anyway.